# EmptyThrowable: Win7TaskBar CoCreateInstance(IID_ITaskbarList3)

Tags: java, android, windows

I face this error recently in Android Studio 1.5.1, and I don't know what this error!

```
EmptyThrowable: Win7TaskBar CoCreateInstance(IID_ITaskbarList3) hResult: -2147221164
```

[image]

how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

> Error code: (HRESULT) 0x80040154 (2147746132) - Class not registered

[ITaskbarList3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692(v=vs.85).aspx) exists on Windows 7 and later but applications should wait for it to become available:

> When an application displays a window, its taskbar button is created by the system. When the button is in place, the taskbar sends a TaskbarButtonCreated message to the window. Your application should call `RegisterWindowMessage(L"TaskbarButtonCreated")` and handle that message in its wndproc. That message must be received by your application before it calls any ITaskbarList3 method.

It could be a problem with your registry, try to check if {EA1AFB91-9E28-4B86-90E9-9E9F8A5EEFAF} is registered correctly by comparing it (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface{EA1AFB91-9E28-4B86-90E9-9E9F8A5EEFAF}) with another computer.

It might also be a application bug so you can try clicking the report error button...